# Find the all the occurrence of pattern in string and then replace in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a very big string from which I wanted to replace a specific substring with another string. Example of sample string:

```
txt = """{u'lang': u'en_US', u'tz': u'Canada/Eastern', u'uid': 1, u'dashboard_merge_domains_contexts': False,      u'group_by': [], u'params': {u'action': 315}}" domain="[[u'state', u'!=', u'done'], [u'state', u'!=', u'cancel'], [u'state', u'!=', u'draft'],      **[u'location_ids', u'ilike', u'WH07']**, [u'state', u'!=', u'done'], [u'state', u'!=', u'cancel'], [u'state', u'!=', u'draft'],      **[u'location_ids', u'=', u'WH123']**]"""
```

I want to replace all square brackets containing location_ids(highlighted) with a new string. is it possible to do? I thought of using regex but I did not find any common pattern.

Comment: Don'r do it that way.  That's old Python code.  So, use `ast.literal_eval` and then go through the list one by one.

Comment: Of course, let me change my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that converts the string back into a Python list of lists, and then parses the list.

```
import ast

txt = "{u'lang': u'en_US', u'tz': u'Canada/Eastern', u'uid': 1, u'dashboard_merge_domains_contexts': False, u'group_by': [], u'params': {u'action': 315}}"
domain="[[u'state', u'!=', u'done'], [u'state', u'!=', u'cancel'], [u'state', u'!=', u'draft'], [u'location_ids', u'ilike', u'WH07'], [u'state', u'!=', u'done'], [u'state', u'!=', u'cancel'], [u'state', u'!=', u'draft'], [u'location_ids', u'=', u'WH123']]"

domain = ast.literal_eval(domain)
print(domain)
for a,b,c in domain:
    if a == 'location_ids':
        print("Found", c)
```

Output:

```
[['state', '!=', 'done'], ['state', '!=', 'cancel'], ['state', '!=', 'draft'], ['location_ids', 'ilike', 'WH07'], ['state', '!=', 'done'], ['state', '!=', 'cancel'], ['state', '!=', 'draft'], ['location_ids', '=', 'WH123']]
Found WH07
Found WH123
```

If you want to change it, it would be something like:

```
newlist = []
for a,b,c in domain:
    if a == 'location_ids':
        c = c.replace('WH','XX')
    newlist.append([a,b,c])
```

Comment: Actually, Domain is not another string. it is part of txt only. txt is one string with domain inside it.  I forgot to add additional quotes. I have edited the string.

Comment: That can't be.  It's not valid syntax.  You can't have that `=` inside.  Where does this information come from?  Is it in file?  Perhaps you should provide a link to the file, so we can all be sure of what you have.

Comment: It is a valid string. you can use type(txt) to check and perform any other string function on it.  I have added a link for the same and can check the results of type(txt) and len(txt).  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nK23.png

Comment: My theory is that you cut-and-pasted that string from some other source, and you cut-and-pasted it incorrectly.  What's inside that string is nonsense.  It is not valid, and helping you to parse that will not solve your problem.  Show us WHERE you got that string from.  Let's get back to the original source, instead of a bad copy, and help you to solve the PROBLEM.